# Ability to vote on User Story?

Tags: tfs

I would like my stake holders to be able to vote on user stories or features in TFS 2013 (or 2015 if this is coming?). The end result is so I can see how much interest there is in a given idea and help prioritize work.  This seems like something that should already be implemented but I am not sure what this is called to be able to properly search for it.

Is this a feature in TFS?
Can I extend TFS to do this?
Or is there a 3rd party product that can integrate with TFS and provide this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can integrate with uservoice to do this. There is a feature called service hooks that allows you to trigger the integration with them and it allows you to do the same as http://visualstudio.uservoice.com

You could also extend TFS to do it yourself with a simple voting webpage and a single numeric field.

Or you could do a "hot or not" implementation to provide that data as an alternative.